# Bootstrap Voting button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a voting system in my page, where I used it with normal css button, which working well. But when I apply it in Bootstrap button, Its not work.

I want to used it in Bootstrap.

Normal css button:

```
<div class="voting_kochi" id="1012">

    <div class="voting_btn"><div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="up_votes">0</span></div>
    <div class="voting_btn"><div class="down_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="down_votes">0</span></div>

</div>
```

Convert to Bootstrap:

```
<div class="voting_kochi" id="1012">

    <div class="voting_btn"><div class="btn btn-default btn-responsive up_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></div><span class="badge btn-responsive up_votes">0</span></div>
    <div class="voting_btn"><div class="btn btn-default btn-responsive down_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></div><span class="badge btn-responsive down_votes">0</span></div>

</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.each( $('.voting_kochi'), function(){
    var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");
    post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};
    $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {
            $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up); 
            $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(response.vote_down);
        },'json');
});

$(".voting_kochi .voting_btn").click(function (e) {
    var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');
    var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 
    if(clicked_button==='down_button') //user disliked the content
    {
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'down'};
        $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {
            $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(data);
        }).fail(function(err) { 
        alert(err.statusText); 
        });             
    }
    else if(clicked_button==='up_button') //user liked the content
    {
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};
        $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {
            $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);
        }).fail(function(err) { 
        alert(err.statusText); 
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: any console errors you are getting???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hasClass().hasClass will check for the presents of a class in the element.try this one

```
$(".voting_kochi .voting_btn").click(function (e) {
    var clicked_button = $(this).children();
    var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 
    if($(clicked_button).hasClass('down_button')) //user disliked the content
    {
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'down'};
        $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {
            $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(data);
        }).fail(function(err) { 
        alert(err.statusText); 
        });             
    }
    else if($(clicked_button).hasClass('up_button')) //user liked the content
    {
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};
        $.post('../vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {
            $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);
        }).fail(function(err) { 
        alert(err.statusText); 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: A console error display `.fail is not a function` in here `.fail(function(err) { ` but voting now working well.